# Элементы удаление из списка

Tags: c++, list

помогите разобраться с удалением элементов списка.При попытке удалить у меня выводить выходит ошибка .Я не понимаю что делать

```
void removeElem(int idx) {
    Node *current = Head;
    Node *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        current = current->Next;

    }//обращение к элементу
    if (current->Prev != NULL )
        current->Prev->Next = current->Next;
    if (current->Next != nullptr) {
        current->Next->Prev = current->Prev;
        delete temp;
    }

}
```

P.S Я еще новичок в программирование, поэтому прошу обьяснить как это работает

Comment: delete temp зачем? что оно удалять будет?

Comment: delete temp  удаляет элемент из списка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, надо проверять, а есть ли такой элемент - ведь может оказаться так, что вы дошли до конца списка и `current` стал равен `NULL` - какой уж тут `current->Next`...

```
for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
    current = current->Next;
}
```

Сами поймете, как проверить?

Во-вторых, после инициализации значением `NULL` вы ни разу, ничего не присвоили переменной `temp`, но вызываете для нее `delete`. Это не запрещено, но бессмысленно...

Опять же - сами разберетесь, какой именно указатель нужно удалять?...

Само собой, все эти замечания имеют смысл, если у вас правильно сформирован список, элементы выделены через `new`, доступен `Head` и так далее.

Еще - ощущение списывания без понимания. Иначе зачем объявлять переменную `i` два раза или одновременно использовать `NULL` и `nullptr`?